# Pandas sort three list columns in descending order with reference to one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, columnsorting

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
df = 
    userid        item_id                   label             score
      1            [1, 2, 3]               [0, 0, 1]          [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]
      ...        ...                            ...
```

`item_id`,  `label` and `score` are the same sized list columns of df (not limited to size 3). I want to sort `score` column in descending order and `label` and `item_id` also should be sorted in reference with the new order of `score` column.

**Expected Output**

```
 df =
     userid.     item_id.       truth       score
       1          [3, 2, 1]   [1, 0, 0]   [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]
```

Is it possible to do this in Pandas?

**How I formed this dataframe:**

I had this data frame originally:

```
  df_original =
       userid        item_id                   label             score
        1              1                         0                 0.2
        1              2                         0                 0.3
        1              3                         1                 0.5
```

I called:

```
  df = df_original.groupby('user_id').agg(list)
```

If there is a way achieving the `Expected Output` from `df_original`, then also it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `sort_values` and `groupby` to convert to list again

```
(df_original.sort_values(['userid', 'score'], ascending=[True,False])
            .groupby('userid').agg(list)
            .reset_index()
)
```

### Edit

As [@Ben.T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9274732/ben-t) warned, it is possible to make it simpler

```
(df_original.sort_values('score', ascending=False)
            .groupby('userid').agg(list)
            .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: why both `True` and `False` in `sort_values`?

Comment: @SumitSidana the True will order the `user_id` from smallest to largest. The False will order the score column to largest to smallest